# Cursor in middle of the screen at start and end of file

Tags: vimrc

I'd like to keep the cursor at the middle of the screen wherever I am in the file, without scrolling. This mean to have blank space above the file when I'm at the start of the file, and have blank space under the file when I'm at the end of the file.

I now there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12838570/3616601) who give a hack (only to have blank space after the file), but we have to remap all keys, which is not really convenient, and it does not work in insert or visual modes.

Comment: There's nothing "not convenient" about remapping keys, assuming you do it in vimrc. Copy the remaps and paste them into your vimrc and you never have to worry about it again. I have a few of them in [my own config](https://github.com/mdebusk/dotfiles/blob/main/.vim/vimrc) and I find them quite useful.

Comment: Having the start of the buffer in the middle of the screen is impossible (it's hard-coded in Vim). For the end of the file, [try this.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26055/343).

Comment: @MDeBusk I think Phantom means that it's inconvenient to map every single possible key that can move the cursor vertically: the list given at the linked page is non-exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

I have part of a solution.

I am not sure for the top of the file, but for the bottom of the file, if you use `CTRL_e` to scroll down, you can scroll as far as having the last line of the file at the top of your screen. You can also use `CTRL_y` to scroll up, but at the top of the file it will not scroll higher.

These two commands allow to scroll the view without moving your cursor (unlike using `k` and `j` to scroll up or down when the cursor is at the top or bottom). It is similar to scrolling with the mouse.

And it works in visual mode, however not in insert mode.

If anyone has suggestions for the uncovered cases (top of the file and insert mode, if it is possible), a completion of this answer would be welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for something automatic. I edited my post.

Comment: So when you move your cursor, you want the the view to automatically move so that it stays in the middle, correct?

Comment: yes, that's it :)

Comment: Fair enough. From what I see online, it seems only possible through mappings, or configurations such as the link you provided or https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Keep_your_cursor_centered_vertically_on_the_screen